# WooCommerce Product Category Image & Category Title On Homepage

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-wordpress-pages, woocommerce-theming

I need to display the latest 8;

- WooCommerce Category Images
  &
- WooCommerce Category Titles
  on my homepage.

I've easily FOREACHED in the titles and href links.
But I can't work out how to get the associated image as well, to create a category tile.

```
// Arguments
$args = array(
    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
    'posts_per_page' => 8,
    'category_name' => $category->name,
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'date' 
);
$categories = get_categories( $args );
foreach( $categories as $category ) { ?>
<a href="<?php echo site_url(product-category) ?><?php echo $category->slug; ?>/">
    <div class="category-tile-image">
        <!-- I NEED THIS -->
        <!-- I NEED THIS -->
        <!-- I NEED THIS -->
        <img src="#">
        <!-- I NEED THIS -->
        <!-- I NEED THIS -->
        <!-- I NEED THIS -->
    </div>
    <h2><?php echo $category->name; ?></h2>
</a>
<?php } ?>
```

Here is the image I'm trying to get to show.

[image]

Comment: @DanG If my answer helped you then please consider [accepting the answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkiIZ.png). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You would need three things in your `foreach` loop in order to output each category image. First, you would need `id of the category` based on which you would get the `id of the image` and then based on that id, you would be able to get the `image url`. So in your `foreach` loop you could do something like this:

```php
$image_id = get_term_meta($category->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true);

$image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_url($image_id, 'thumbnail'); ?>

<img src="<?php echo $image_url; ?>">
```

So your entire code would be something like this:

```php
$args = array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'posts_per_page' => 8,
            'category_name' => $category->name,
            'orderby' => 'date',
            'order' => 'date'
        );
        $categories = get_categories($args);
        foreach($categories as $category) {
            $image_id = get_term_meta($category->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true);
            $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_url($image_id, 'thumbnail');
    ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $category->slug; ?>/">
                <div class="category-tile-image">

                    <img src="<?php echo $image_url; ?>">

                </div>
                <h2><?php echo $category->name; ?></h2>
            </a>
<?php }
```

And here's the results:

[image]

You could see the image for those categories that have a thumbnail, and those that don't have a thumbnail, it won't show anything!